# SimpleDateFormat date comes in arabic

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date, simpledateformat

I download the user's date data and write this data to firebase. However, the date format will not work correctly when data is added from Arabic locations.
How can I fix this?

Output:

```
"٢٠٢١-٠٤-١٧"
```

My Code:

```
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
            String currentDateandTime = df.format(new Date());
```

I do not want to receive data in Arabic alphabet. I should take the data as 17/04/2021 under any condition. Not as /١٧/٢٠٢١.

Comment: have you tried Locale.ROOT

Comment: So that we know that we understand each other, could you be specific and precise about the expected/desired result?

Answer (score 5):

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfEnglish = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfArabic = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH)
                .localizedBy(new Locale("ar"));

        // Change the ZoneId as per your requirement e.g. ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai")
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.println(date.format(dtfEnglish));
        System.out.println(date.format(dtfArabic));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
18/04/2021
١٨/٠٤/٢٠٢١
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I do not want to receive data in Arabic alphabet. I should take the data as 17/04/2021 under any condition. Not as /١٧/٢٠٢١.

Comment: @MustapTR - I've updated the answer to include the English version as well. Use whichever meets your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. If I have understood that Firebase doesn’t provide a `date` data type, then I think that for storing you will want:

```
    String currentDateandTime = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toString();
    System.out.println(currentDateandTime);
```

Output when running just now in my time zone:

> 2021-04-17

The result is independent of locale. On retrieval the one-arg `LocalDate.parse(CharSequence)` will parse the same string back into a `LocalDate`.

Edit: The format you want, 2021-04-17, is an international standard known as ISO 8601, and I consider it wise of you to use it in your program too. I am exploiting the fact that `LocalDate` and the other classes of java.time produce ISO 8601 from their `toString` methods and parse the same format back in their one-arg `parse` methods. So when dealing with ISO 8601 (as a rule) we don’t need to specify a format nor a formatter neither for formatting nor for parsing. Had you wanted a different format, you would have used a `DateTimeFormatter` for specifying it.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Edit: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I don't know how to set the date format I want with this Example : yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: @MustapTR Sorry, that wasn’t clear. I have edited, I hope it helps. The trick is (perhaps surprising) that we don’t set the format. yyyy-MM-dd is the format that we get when we don’t set any.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the data as 17/04/2021 under any condition, you could just change the second argument to be Locale.US .

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
String currentDateandTime = df.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Correct, but as said in the other answers one should not want to use `SimpleDateFormat` in the 2020s.

Comment: The poorly-designed `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.